# How do I get this justify-content to work? (Using flexbox)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, media-queries

Hey guys i'm doing a small practice project for uni and came across this problem. I've tried many ways none seem to work. I am trying to use justify content while having the flexbox with a flex-direction of row (overriding the sites original of flex-direction: column). Also display: flex is not needed to be displayed because it is displayed in a seperate style sheet, outside the media query. Any help would be great thanks.

This is the code in the media query, please note it is a SASS file.

```
.testimonials{
    padding: 50px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<section class="testimonials">
        <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
            <div class="speech_box">
                <p>The moment our customers and even competitors started asking who dos your beautiful design, we knew that we has found a gret designer</p>
            </div>
            <p><span>Oliver Auerbach,</span> Founder &#38; CEO</p>
            <p>GloriaFood</p>
        </article>
        <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
            <div class="speech_box">
                <p>Bota delivers quality work at competitive rates. He creates beautiful and simle user interfaces in line with your business objectives.</p>
            </div>
                <p><span>Rikard Stolz,</span> Senior Conversion and UX Planner</p>
                <p>JBA Digital</p>
        </article>
        <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
            <div class="speech_box">
                <p>Bota is the most talented designer and front-end developer i have worked with. He has an amazing ability to understand the mission and puts great passion in what he does. He truly is great and i would recommend him for his full professionalism.</p>
            </div>
                <p><span>Pierre Landmark,</span> Co-Founder of Foxshare</p>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Its purpose is to look like this

[image]

But its looking like this

[image]

Also none of the properties for justify-content are working

[image]

Comment: None of the properties for justify-content work.

Comment: Is that all of the code that we need?  It's not showing the same as the images.

Comment: Ill send a code pen. May be hard to view seeing it is set within a media query

Comment: https://codepen.io/dalhog9/pen/GMGaow         The ID of "testimonials" starts on line 99.

Answer (score 0):

The articles **need** a width so that *space-around* or *space-between* can work. On smaller screens set the width to 100%.

```css
.testimonials {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.testimonials>article {
  width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .testimonials>article {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonials">
  <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
    <div class="speech_box">
      <p>The moment our customers and even competitors started asking who dos your beautiful design, we knew that we has found a gret designer</p>
    </div>
    <p><span>Oliver Auerbach,</span> Founder &#38; CEO</p>
    <p>GloriaFood</p>
  </article>
  <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
    <div class="speech_box">
      <p>Bota delivers quality work at competitive rates. He creates beautiful and simle user interfaces in line with your business objectives.</p>
    </div>
    <p><span>Rikard Stolz,</span> Senior Conversion and UX Planner</p>
    <p>JBA Digital</p>
  </article>
  <article class="testimonial_InnerContain">
    <div class="speech_box">
      <p>Bota is the most talented designer and front-end developer i have worked with. He has an amazing ability to understand the mission and puts great passion in what he does. He truly is great and i would recommend him for his full professionalism.</p>
    </div>
    <p><span>Pierre Landmark,</span> Co-Founder of Foxshare</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

---

In the codepen example (at about line 22), you can do

```
...
#testimonials {
  padding: 50px;
  flex-direction: row !important; // Add !important
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.testimonial_InnerContain { // Add this class of article and give it a width
  width: 30%;
}
...
```